# Reading both newline types from an already opened file in python

Tags: python, io, stream, newline, readline

I'm using subprocess.popen to run a command and grab the stdout.

It so happens that the program (mplayer) sort of uses both eol types `\n` and `\r`. The `\r`s come from terminal control characters. So the output I end up with are regular lines interspersed with really long lines where the `\r`s were ignored.

I know if I had opened a file myself, I could set the newline type. However, I'm getting the stdout from popen so I have no control over that.

I had a look at the python 2.7 source and I image I can somehow use TextIOWrapper to respect both eol types. However I'm not too sure what I need to pass to it. I know I need to pass the constructor some sort of buffer, but I don't know how to get the buffer from an already opened file.

All in all, how to I `readline()` in python that breaks at both `\n` and `\r` given an already open file/stream?

Comment: I'm *pretty* sure that mplayer has an output format that's *much* less useless for reprocessing...

Comment: I had a look at the mplayer source and there doesn't look like as if there is any way to turn it off.

Comment: Is the [mplayer.py](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mplayer.py/0.7.0) wrapper module useful for you, or does it lack functionality you need and you actually need to invoke *mplayer* directly?

Comment: The module is probably a bit overkill. I'm just parsing the stdout of mplayer for basic information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Popen.subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) (and [Popen.check_output](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) if the convenience function is enough for you), have a `universal_newlines` parameter which by default is `False`, but when set to `True` will give you the behaviour you need of converting all newline variants to `\n`.